# Django Queryset for date

Tags: python, django

Does anyone know the quickest way to delete any entries from a database that is older then 6 months.
So far Ive been using...

```
Example.objects.filter(date_created__lte="2011-2-9  12:00:00" ).delete()
```

Thanks,

Comment: do you have error message for your try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
Example.objects.filter(date_created__lte=datetime.utcnow() - 
                          timedelta(days=6*30)).delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this if your date_created is of type datetimefield

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

six_months = datetime.now() - timedelta(weeks=24)
Example.objects.filter(date_created__lte=six_months).delete()
```